# syntax error when writing a class component method in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await

Is this code:

```
async onSearchSubmit(term) { 
        const response = await axios.get('https://api.somewebsite.com/search/photos', {
            params: {query: term},
            headers:{
                Authorization: 'Client-ID some Access KEY'
            }
        }) 
        console.log(response.data.results)
    }
```

and this code :

```
 onSearchSubmit: async function(term) { 
        const response = await axios.get('https:///api.somewebsite.com/search/photos', {
            params: {query: term},
            headers:{
                Authorization: 'Client-ID some Access KEY'
            }
        }) 
        console.log(response.data.results)
    }
```

are not equivalent? Notice I only change how I wrote the class method. The only change is `async onSearchSubmit(term)` to  `onSearchSubmit: async function(term)` . First one is working perfectly. At the second one, I am getting Parsing error: Unexpected token ";".  Please save me before I go blind.

Answer (score 1):

You missed the params, it should be

```js
onSearchSubmit: async function (term) {
  const response = await axios.get(
    "https:///api.somewebsite.com/search/photos",
    {
      params: { query: term },
      headers: {
        Authorization: "Client-ID some Access KEY",
      },
    }
  )
  console.log(response.data.results)
}
```

Comment: ah sorry. I missed when writing the question. I edited now. The problem still persists.

Comment: could you show me the file that including these funcs?